# Strange TLE problem for bachet's game in Kattis/UVA10404 using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, dynamic-programming

It's known as Bachet's game which is quite interesting.

I use DP and the idea is not complicated but I got TLE as using of Python. I tried to optimize the code but failed. I saw a similar code written in C but get accepted. I just wonder if it is a problem of Kattis...

Could anyone know how to optimize it or point out what corner case my code my meets.

Here is the [problem description](https://open.kattis.com/problems/bachetsgame).

Here is my code:

```py
from sys import stdin
lines = stdin.readlines()
i= 0
while i < len(lines):
    line = [int(x) for x in lines[i].split()]
    n, m, group = line[0], line[1], line[2:]
    #dp[i] means stan will win if i stones left when his turn to move
    dp = [False for _ in range(n+1)]
    # for j in group:
    #     if j < n:
    #         dp[j] = True
    for k in range(1, n+1):
        for j in group:
            if k >= j and (not dp[k-j]):
                dp[k] = True 
                break
    if dp[-1]:
        print("Stan wins\n")
    else:
        print("Ollie wins\n")
    
    i += 1
```

This [similar code](https://github.com/marioyc/Online-Judge-Solutions/blob/master/UVA/Contest%20Volumes/10404%20-%20Bachet%27s%20Game.cpp) written in C gets accepted.